# Gatsby + DatoCMS, how do I add a new page?

Tags: gatsby

I'm stuck (first time trying to use GatsbyJS + DatoCMS + Netlify). I added a new page in DatoCMS and I also added it to my repo [here](https://github.com/TobiasDev/johansson-tobias-com)

However, I can't get the build to work since I get this error: "There was an error in your GraphQL query: Cannot query field "datoCmsCvPage" on type "Query"."  - I understand why I'm getting the error, however, I don't know how to add this to my GraphQL query anywhere. Could anyone just explain to me how I would get this working and added?

Answer (score 0):

The error means that there isn't a model associated to that name. Are you sure you are using the correct model name? :)

Comment: I notice the repo linked in the question is a lot newer than the question.  Would you be able to look at it and determine whether the original user solved their problem? (And perhaps note how they did it for other users?)

Comment: Looking at the commit history it looks like it was solved by changing the name.